# Showing all odd numbers instead of prime numbers

Tags: python, primes

```
def prime_num_gen():
    
    try:
        r = int(input('Type in the number till which you want to generate your prime numbers : '))
    
        if r <= 2:
             print('There is no prime number smaller than 2, 2 is the smallest prime number')
    
        #A list to store primes
        #Storing 2 already, because I need a number to start with
        prime_num = [2] 
    
        #Counter
        #Counter will be divided and if it's a prime; will append it
        x = 3
    
        #Starting with 3 cus 2 is already considered
        #Having a jump of 2, cus no even num is prime, so considering only odd nums
        while x <= r:
            for num in range(3,x,2):
    
                if num % x == 0:
                    x += 2
                    break 
    
            else:
                prime_num.append(x)
                x += 2 
    
        print(prime_num)
    
    except:
        print('Please only give input as a number!\nTry again')
```

For some reason, this code is including all odd numbers as prime numbers. I am complete a novice in coding and even if this seems like a pretty obvious mistake, please tell me so .

Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: Your division check is written incorrectly. Instead of `num % x` you want `x % num`.

Comment: Thank you! It straight up fixed it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a small bug in your code. Instead of the condition

```
if num % x == 0:
```

You should do

```
if x % num == 0:
```

Since num will always be smaller than or equal to x, so its modulus with x will always give the number once again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different implementation that can be faster in different ranges.  **The basic algorithm is quite simple**.

```
def isprime(n):
    for i in range(2,int(n**0.5)+1):
        if n%i == 0: 
            return False
    return True
for i in range (1,100):
    if isprime(i) == True:
        print(i)
```

It takes **O(N log (log N))** time to find all prime numbers less than N.